# jQuery get values from selected checkboxes

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, arrays

First problem is that I do not know how to get the values of SPECIFC checkboxes when they are checked.

I need a function that will get the value of the selected checkboxes by checkbox ID or Name.

This is the code I have so far:

```
    $("#doStatus").click(function(){
    var Tuitting = $('textarea#tuitting').val();
    var F = $('input#Fb').val(); //checkboxes with ID Fb
    var T = $('input#Tw').val(); //checkboxes with ID Tw
$.get("<?echo $site['url'];?>modules/yobilab/tuitting_core/classes/doStatusBox.php", { tuitting: Tuitting, f: F, t: T });
 window.setTimeout('location.reload()', 1000);
return false;
});
```

Now the second problem is that both var F and var T may contain MORE than one values in an array..

Obviously when I use the ajax get functions the multiple values for both var F and var T are not 
passed at all. What is the problem..?

How do I pass multiple values in an array that will be then runed by  the foreach on the doStatusBox.php page?

Please help me.

Comment: would you mind to post the sourrended html code pease?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm answering based on an assumption: you need checked checkboxes to pass them via GET method to your `doStatusBox.php` script.

However, why would you go trough the trouble of finding which checkbox is checked if you can simply use the serialize() method and let jQuery do the job for you?

```
$("#doStatus").click(function()
{
    var serialized = $("#someFormHere").serialize() 
    // or, if you have your form elements within a div or another element 
    var serialized = $("#elementID :input").serialize();

    $.get("<?echo $site['url'];?>modules/yobilab/tuitting_core/classes/doStatusBox.php", serialized);
    window.setTimeout('location.reload()', 1000);

    return false;
});
```

However, is "#doStatus" a submit button submitting the form or something else? If it submits the form, bind the submit event to the form, not click event to the button submitting it.

Comment: it returns this: tuitting=test&f%5B%5D=2&f%5B%5D=4&f%5B%5D=8&t%5B%5D=2&t%5B%5D=3&t%5B%5D=4  Will the php foreach loop be able to get that array of values?? or is there something else I should do?

Comment: Yes, that's a proper query string. Try it and you'll see, any post or get data is passed that way if it's an array.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#doStatus").click(function() {
    var Tuitting = $('textarea#tuitting').val();
    var F = $('input[name="fb"] :selected').val();

   //You can give the name of checkbox and get the values of selected checkbox
   return false;
});
```

Comment: ok but what about when there are more values inside f or t?? I am using a mysql while that will give me more results and the users can select more f or t checkboxes that will have different values, all of those values should then be sent to the php page called by ajax..How do I do that?